# Why does this shell script with sbcl --version print a newline before the echo output?

Tags: bash, shell

The following script prints a newline before the first word printed by echo.  Why?

**Environment:**

- macOS Mojave
- using either system sh (which is GNU bash 3.2.57(1), or GNU bash 5.1.8(1)

**Description**

Here's the script, which I tried with different shebang lines (bash or sh) ending with the same problem:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
which sbcl  > /dev/null
status=$?
if [ $status -eq 0 ]; then
    export PGMFOR_LISP=`which sbcl`
    echo -1-
    echo "Using Common Lisp - " `sbcl --version` "- from:" $PGMFOR_LISP
    echo -2-
else
    echo "**Error!** Request to use SBCL, but fail to find it in PATH!"
fi
```

It prints the following:

```
-1-

Using Common Lisp -  SBCL 2.1.4 - from: /usr/local/bin/sbcl
-2-
```

The issue I have is the empty line between the `-1-` line and the `Using Common Lisp ...` line.

The above uses `sbcl --version` to get the version.  It prints on stdout and does print a newline before the string it outputs.  I assume the problem comes from that, but I have not been able to fix it with `tr -d` for example.

Here's the following extra tests:

```bsh
>Pierres-iMac@Fri May 14@07:25:39[~]
> sbcl --version 2>/dev/null | od -tc
0000000    S   B   C   L       2   .   1   .   4  \n                    
0000013

>Pierres-iMac@Fri May 14@07:26:06[~]
> sbcl --version 2>/dev/null | hexdump
0000000 53 42 43 4c 20 32 2e 31 2e 34 0a               
000000b

>Pierres-iMac@Fri May 14@07:30:19[~]
>
```

How can I get rid of that extra empty line?

Comment: If you run `echo go; sbcl --version >/dev/null; echo done` do you get a blank line between `go` and `done`?

Comment: Are you trying to set `$PGMFOR_LISP` for the user, or just while your script runs?

Comment: @FrankThomas: No change occurs if I quote and replace the line with:  echo "-1-", it still issues a newline.

Comment: @roima, I'm doing both: I am using it inside the script and also use it later, after the script has run.

Comment: This script cannot set `$PGMFOR_LISP` for its caller unless you are using `. script` or possibly `source script`

Comment: @roima, you are correct, and I should have mentioned that, I'm accessing that script via an alias that sources the script.

Comment: @roima, if I try `echo go; sbcl --version >/dev/null; echo done`  then 3 lines are printed, one with go, an empty line and the done.

Comment: sbcl seems to output to the standard error stream.    If I replace the `>/dev/null` by `2>/dev/null` no empty line show between go and done.  **However** if I use ```echo "Using Common Lisp - " `sbcl --version 2>/dev/null` "- from:" $PGMFOR_LISP``` it still outputs an empty line.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my question, basically to say I cannot reproduce the blank line you're describing. Sorry.

Comment: @roaima.  No problem.  Thanks for trying.  BTW I have similar scripts that pint the version of python, gcc, rust, etc... and I have no problem with them.  The one with sbcl is the oddball one.

Answer (score 0):

```
# source me
if which sbcl >/dev/null
then
    export PGMFOR_LISP=`which sbcl`
    printf "%s\n" '-1-'
    printf "Using Common Lisp - %s - from %s\n" "$(sbcl --version 2>/dev/null)" "$PGMFOR_LISP"
    printf "%s\n" '-2-'
else
    echo '**Error!** Request to use SBCL, but fail to find it in PATH!'
fi
```

There's little point having an initial `#!` line because this script can only usefully be `source`d (possibly with `.`, again depending on the shell).

I've replaced the `echo -1-` type lines because using `echo` with an argument that starts with a dash is not well defined - different shells will do different things.

---

For the purposes of testing the apparently strange behaviour of `sbcl --version`, I've used this mockup test script, executable and in my `$PATH`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo >&2
echo "SBCL 2.1.4"
```

I cannot reproduce the extra blank line you're reporting

```
export PGMFOR_LISP=`which sbcl`
printf "Using Common Lisp - %s - from %s\n" "$(sbcl --version 2>/dev/null)" "$PGMFOR_LISP"
```

results in just the single line

```
Using Common Lisp - SBCL 2.1.4 - from /home/roaima/bin/sbcl
```

Comment: @roima I tried it verbatim and it's still printing the empty line between `-1-` and `Using...`  I assume it works in your environment?

Comment: BTW, the echo "-1-" and "-2" are only in there to show the empty line.  I'd normally would not have these lines.  But thanks for pointing out the potential portability issue with it.

Comment: I just saw a SO tag for SBCL, I check if there is info there.